# htaccess mod rewrite problem

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirection

Let me start immediately with my problem:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ sinj.com.hr/$1/$2/$3/$4 [R=301,L]
```

There is folder `sinj.com.hr/administracija` and when I try to access `http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija` I am redirected to

> http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija?var1=administracija

What I would like is when user enters `http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija` that he is redirected to `http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija/index.php`. I tried to do this with header("Location:... ") but it always redirects me to `http://localhost/sinj.com.hr/administracija?var1=administracija`. If folder administracija is renamed then header() function works. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks, Ile

Comment: What's in your `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: http://www.ilijaveselica.com/sinj.com.hr/httpdconf.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing on my own Apache configuration I created the directory `DOCUMENT_ROOT/sinj.com.hr` and placed the `.htaccess` file in there along with a simple `index.php` file that just dumped the $_REQUEST contents back to me.

Here is the `.htaccess` I used:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /sinj.com.hr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sinj.com.hr/index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?var1=$1 [R,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [R,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [R,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [R,L,QSA]
```

The *RewriteCond* line catches the `index.php` to keep it from going into a recursive loop. I also gave each *RewriteRule* the redirect (R) and query string append (QSA) flags in addition to tell them they were the last (L) rule to apply.

I also changed the match grouping to include anything except a slash (/) to simplify the matching.

Comment: No problem... I've had my own go-rounds with mod_rewrite... it can be a tricky bastard to nail down sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm...what about trying the

```
DirectoryIndex
```

directive in the .htaccess file under the administracija folder?  In this case, I'd specifically suggest:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Only when I remove last 4 lines from htaccess then it works... actually I'm still redirected to the same address but this time content is displayed. Also, I don't know how users are going to reach forum because this is going to existing portal and users are used to reach content via specific url which is now not accessible.

Comment: I found solution on stackoverflow: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php` And it must be places before last 4 lines in above example

Answer (score 0):

couldnt get text being displayed as code in comment so I'll have to use answer...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The following rule is causing the behavior:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
```

That is redirecting `/sinj.com.hr/administracija` to `sinj.com.hr/index.php?var1=administracija`